# TFS2012 Merging issue with branch after rollback the trunk change

Tags: .net, tfs, tfsbuild

Below is the chronology of the Merge and branching.

1. 4/15 - Create a branch BRCH1 from Trunk which has three subfolder A, B, C
2. 6/18 - Merge the changes from branch to Trunk including A, B, C. 90 files change shown
3. 6/19 - Create another BRCH2 from Trunk with same subfolder A, B, C
4. 6/20 - Rollback the Trunk changes.
5. 6/21 to 7/6 - Made changes in BRCH2. In the meanwhile, there are couple of checked in trunk. All the changes were updated to BRCH2 as well.
6. 7/7 - Try re-integrating to Trunk from BRCH2. Now showing only 20 files changes.

Why it is showing discrepancy. I checked few files and found that changes are present in BRCH2 and not showing in Trunk on merge.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem is?

So when you created the branch BRCH2 (Step 3), all the 90 changes are already in BRCH 2. As long as your are merging all changes in Truck forward to BRCH2 before merging back, you will only get the changes which were made specifically in BRNCH2 in your merge back.

Comment: Yes. All 90 files were present in BRCH2

Comment: So what is the issue then? Did you understand the reason for discrepancy?

Comment: It seems the rollback is the rootcause.

Comment: Did you not merge your rollback up to BRCH2? Remember, you will need to update all changes in parent branch to child branch before you merge them back from child branch

Comment: We do not want to rollback same in BRCH2 as that changes definitely required

Comment: So, herein lies the problem. You are trying to merge to a different baseline.